# Multiple instances of same component trigger same event handler

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a very simple component, which has a text field and a custom browse file button (with a hidden FileInput). On my page I have this component represented twice, each with a hook to their own Callback action.
The problem is that when the callback is triggered, it seems to execute the same callback action on my page (both components triggers Callback1 on the page).
Can anyone help to see what I am missing? I am rather new on Blazor and I cannot see the missing link here.

**Page**

```
@page "/"
<div id="component1">
    <FileSelectorComponent Title="Component1" PathChanged="Callback1"/>
</div>
<label for="component1">@_path1</label>

<div id="component2">
    <FileSelectorComponent Title="Component2" PathChanged="Callback2"/>
</div>
<label for="component2">@_path2</label>


@code {
    private string? _path1;
    private string? _path2;

    protected void Callback1(IBrowserFile file)
    {
        _path1 = $"Size: {file.Size} | Name: {file.Name}";
    }

    protected void Callback2(IBrowserFile file)
    {
        _path2 = $"Size: {file.Size} | Name: {file.Name}";
    }

}
```

**Component**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pathText" readonly="readonly" value="@_path" placeholder="Select file..." />
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="openDialog">
    <label for="file">Browse</label>
</button>
<InputFile id="file" accept=".csv" OnChange="UpdatePath" hidden />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "FileSelectorComponent";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IBrowserFile> PathChanged { get; set; }

    private string? _path;

    private async Task UpdatePath(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _path = e.File.Name;
        await PathChanged.InvokeAsync(e.File);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are setting the input id inside the component, which will mean that you have two elements in the DOM with the same id. Can you try setting the id dynamically by passing it in as a parameter.

Comment: Good point @KurtHamilton that the elements in the DOM will have the same ID. I did go with the solution below as I feel it as a more clean solution than passing Id parameters to the component from parent.

Comment: The accepted answer works for the same reason - although it doesn't explain WHY it works - just that you can take a different approach. Either way - glad your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a button you want a label that looks like a button, wrapping your label like this removes the need for `id`'s and `for`s:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="pathText" readonly="readonly" value="@_path" placeholder="Select file..." />
<label>
    <text class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Browse</text>
    <InputFile accept=".csv" OnChange="UpdatePath" hidden />
</label>
@code {

    [Parameter]
    [EditorRequired]
    public string Title { get; set; } = "FileSelectorComponent";

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<IBrowserFile> PathChanged { get; set; }

    private string? _path;

    private async Task UpdatePath(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        _path = e.File.Name;
        await PathChanged.InvokeAsync(e.File);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Feels like HTML magic, but probably because I am still rather new in this field.